# Removing a section's rule when it starts a page

Tags: fancyhdr, titlesec

I am currently using the titlesec package in order to personalise my chapter and section headings with these commands:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openright, english]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum} % to produce dummy text
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[small,sf]{titlesec}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
%  \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
%  \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection~ #1}}
 \fancyhead[LE]{$\cdot$~\thepage~$\cdot$\rule{5mm}{0pt}\leftmark}
 \fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark\rule{5mm}{0pt}$\cdot$~\thepage~$\cdot$}
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt} 

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\large\titlerule}
{\sf \thesection}{3mm}{} 

\begin{document}
%
\chapter{Basic principles}
\section{Introduction}
    \lipsum[3-5] % dummy text  
\section{New Style}
    \lipsum[6-9] % dummy text        
\subsection{Image processing}
    \lipsum[3] % dummy text

\end{document}
```

However, I would like to prevent the package from drawing a line above a section heading when it appears at the top of a page. I use the fancyhdr package to draw a line under the header of the page and would prefer to not have the duplicate line at the top of a page if that is where a new section begins.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use leaders, which disappear at page breaks. However, they aren't directly supported in LaTeX, so one has to resort to lower level features.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum} % to produce dummy text
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[small,sf]{titlesec}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
%  \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
%  \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection~ #1}}
 \fancyhead[LE]{$\cdot$~\thepage~$\cdot$\rule{5mm}{0pt}\leftmark}
 \fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark\rule{5mm}{0pt}$\cdot$~\thepage~$\cdot$}
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt} 

\titleformat{\section}[hang]
  {\leaders\vrule width \textwidth\vskip0.4pt \large}
  {\sffamily\thesection}
  {3mm}
  {} 

\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Basic principles}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[3-5] % dummy text  

\section{New Style}
\lipsum[6-9] % dummy text        

\subsection{Image processing}
\lipsum[3] % dummy text

\end{document}
```

[image]